# NameError: name 'ftp' is not defined, Python

Tags: python, ftp, global-variables, nameerror

I am getting this error even though I declared ftp.

Here is the complete error message:

```
File "./sFTPscript.py", line 173, in <module> main()
File "./sFTPscript.py", line 167, in main uploadFTP()
File "./sFTPscript.py", line 33, in uploadFTP ftp.pwd()

NameError: name 'ftp' is not defined
```

--

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os
import sys
import kunden.config as config


def connFTP():
ftp = FTP(config.host)
ftp.login(config.username,config.password)
print("connected")

def uploadFTP():
os.chdir(config.localpath)
ftp.pwd()
ftp.cwd('test')
list_local = os.listdir(config.localpath)
for file in list_local:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR '+file, open(file,'rb'))

return list_local

def main():

    connFTP()
    uploadFTP()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried to make ftp a global variable before it get used but still the same error

Comment: Please fix the indentation and include the full error message. Most probably you forgot to declare `ftp` as `global`.

Comment: `ftp` is not known within `uploadFTP()`. Use a class or pass the object around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ftp` is not known within the scope of `uploadFTP()`. Either use a class, a global variable (use `global ftp`) or pass the object around. The latter could be:

```
def connFTP():
    ftp = FTP(config.host)
    ftp.login(config.username,config.password)
    print("connected")
    return ftp
    #      ^^^

def uploadFTP(ftp=None):
    os.chdir(config.localpath)
    ftp.pwd()
    ftp.cwd('test')
    list_local = os.listdir(config.localpath)
    for file in list_local:
        ftp.storbinary('STOR '+file, open(file,'rb'))
    
    return list_local

def main():

    ftp = connFTP()
    uploadFTP(ftp)
    #         ^^^

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, you do not do anything with the returned `list_local` from `uploadFTP()` (yet?).

Comment: Thank you very much. 
The  list_local is for another function which i did not include in this thread.